# Visual tool for oracle database architecture

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

Could anybody suggest me a visual tool for oracle database architecture. I have used mysql workbench for mysql server. I am trying to find out same kind of tool for oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean tools that include a graphical query builder you should have a look at the following tools:

- [Toad (there is a freeware version, but I am not sure if it contains enough for you)](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa)
- [SQL Developer (free)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

There are other options out there, but I would say that these two are by far the best ones you can get for oracle development.

If you meant tools to create a database (so a graphical tools that shows you a diagram of the database and generates SQL scripts from it) you should have a look at:

- [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/)
- [Dezign](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/)
- [SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html)